# Combine overlapping rectangles, compare overlap to both rectangles and replace both by bounding rectangle

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

i'm working on comparing bounding boxes and combining boxes that overlap too much. I got it working with this code from another post:

```
def non_max_suppression_fast(boxes, overlapThresh):
   # if there are no boxes, return an empty list
   if len(boxes) == 0:
      return []

   # if the bounding boxes integers, convert them to floats --
   # this is important since we'll be doing a bunch of divisions
   if boxes.dtype.kind == "i":
      boxes = boxes.astype("float")
#  
   # initialize the list of picked indexes   
   pick = []

   # grab the coordinates of the bounding boxes
   x1 = boxes[:,0]
   y1 = boxes[:,1]
   x2 = boxes[:,2]
   y2 = boxes[:,3]

   # compute the area of the bounding boxes and sort the bounding
   # boxes by the bottom-right y-coordinate of the bounding box
   area = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)
   idxs = np.argsort(y2)

   # keep looping while some indexes still remain in the indexes
   # list
   while len(idxs) > 0:
      # grab the last index in the indexes list and add the
      # index value to the list of picked indexes
      last = len(idxs) - 1
      i = idxs[last]
      pick.append(i)

      # find the largest (x, y) coordinates for the start of
      # the bounding box and the smallest (x, y) coordinates
      # for the end of the bounding box
      xx1 = np.maximum(x1[i], x1[idxs[:last]])
      yy1 = np.maximum(y1[i], y1[idxs[:last]])
      xx2 = np.minimum(x2[i], x2[idxs[:last]])
      yy2 = np.minimum(y2[i], y2[idxs[:last]])

      # compute the width and height of the bounding box
      w = np.maximum(0, xx2 - xx1 + 1)
      h = np.maximum(0, yy2 - yy1 + 1)

      # compute the ratio of overlap
      overlap = (w * h) / area[idxs[:last]]

      # delete all indexes from the index list that have
      idxs = np.delete(idxs, np.concatenate(([last],
         np.where(overlap > overlapThresh)[0])))

   # return only the bounding boxes that were picked using the
   # integer data type
   return boxes[pick].astype("int")
```

I had two issues with it: This code only compares the overlap from the first to bounding box, meaning that if I check how much of the bigger box is overlapped, the percentage is way smaller than the percentage of the overlap of the smaller box. I solved it with replacing the overlap fucntion with this:

> ```
>  overlap = np.maximum((w * h) / area[idxs[:last]],(w * h) / area[i])
> ```

This seems to work.

But now I have another problem: If two overlapping boxes are found, the code does not replace those two boxes by a new box that is as big as the outer corners of the two boxes. It just deletes one of the boxes and leaves the other one, even if it's the smaller one. 
How can I solve this? I would like to replace those boxes by a bigger bounding box.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using this code with `findContours` function?

Comment: I use a combination of Canny and findcontours: edge = cv.Canny(gray, thrs1, thrs2, apertureSize=5)......_, cnts, _= cv.findContours(edge.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)